# Youtube API v3 : using service account to list videos

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to use Google Service Account to list videos from YouTube Data API v3. I activated YouTube API, created Account Service, but whenever I try to list videos from my channel, it says 0 videos even if I do have uploaded videos.

I ran samples from their docs but it seems like my credentials list videos from my service account directly and not my real YouTube account.

```
List<String> scopes = Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube");

JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(httpTransport)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("youtube-****serviceaccount.com")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(scopes)               
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File("C:\\tmp\\youtube.p12"))
            .build();

youtube = new YouTube.Builder(Auth.HTTP_TRANSPORT, Auth.JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(
            "youtube-cmdline-uploadvideo-sample").build();
YouTube.Channels.List channelRequest = youtube.channels().list("contentDetails");
        channelRequest.setMine(true);
        ChannelListResponse channelResult = channelRequest.execute();

    List<Channel> channelsList = channelResult.getItems();


    String uploadPlaylistId = channelsList.get(0).getContentDetails().getRelatedPlaylists().getUploads();
```

`uploadPlaylistId` should be here my channel ID, but I do not know what it is, all I know it's that this is an empty channel. (If i check here using my real ID channel, I can list my uploads, it seems my service account does not refer correctly on my YouTube account...)

Comment: the YouTube API doesn't support service accounts you need to use Oauth2

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that you are trying to use a service account with the YouTube API.  Service accounts are by default dummy users with there own accounts.   The service account does not have anything uploaded to its account and I don't think you can upload anything to it.

Normally with the Google APIs you would grant the service account access to your account by adding it as a user or granting it permissions some how.  Unfortunately this is not possible with the YouTube API.

if you try and use a service account with the YouTube api you will normally see this error.

> unauthorized (401)    youtubeSignupRequired
>
> This error is commonly seen if you try to use the OAuth 2.0 Service
>   Account flow. YouTube does not support Service Accounts, and if you
>   attempt to authenticate using a Service Account, you will get this
>   error.

The above information can be found in the YouTube Data API Error documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors)

You will need to switch to using Oauth2

Comment: Yes, I read that, ... that is crazy that's impossible... Anyhow, how could I do that without having user consentment at every request ?

Comment: Use Oauth2 save the refresh token use it to get the access token when you need to access the data.